# Plotting branching movement with dplyr + ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to illustrate how input-bits affect output-bits in a four-step rotating hash. The hash function looks like this:

```
#define rot(x,k) (((x)<<(k)) | ((x)>>(32-(k))))
uint32_t rotating_hash(uint32_t state, uint32_t input)
{
    uint32_t hash = state;
    uint8_t *p = (uint8_t*)&input;
    //      mix          ; combine
    hash ^=                *(p++);
    hash += rot(hash, 4) ^ *(p++);
    hash += rot(hash, 4) ^ *(p++);
    hash += rot(hash, 4) ^ *p;
    return hash;
}
```

where, for simplicity, I assume that bits in an addition only affect the same position they are already in. The actual function is not so important, but it is a process in which every bit at one step affects two bits below it.

I compute the way bits at one level affects those below them like this:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

rot_hash_positions <- function(bit) {
  operation_1 <- bit
  operation_2 <- outer(operation_1, c(4, 0, -28), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% { . %% 32 }
  operation_3 <- outer(operation_2, c(4, 0, -28), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% { . %% 32 }
  operation_4 <- outer(operation_3, c(4, 0, -28), FUN = '+')  %>% as.vector() %>% { . %% 32 }
  rbind(tibble(bit = bit, operation = 1, positions = operation_1),
        tibble(bit = bit, operation = 2, positions = operation_2),
        tibble(bit = bit, operation = 3, positions = operation_3),
        tibble(bit = bit, operation = 4, positions = operation_4))
}

bit_movement <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:31, rot_hash_positions))
```

and the result looks like this:

```
> bit_movement %>% filter(bit == 0)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
     bit operation positions
   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     0         1         0
 2     0         2         4
 3     0         2         0
 4     0         3         8
 5     0         3         4
 6     0         3         0
 7     0         4        12
 8     0         4         8
 9     0         4         4
10     0         4         0
```

The function computes two values for the rotate operation, but modulus 32 this become one position and I get rid of duplications using `unique()`.

Now I want to plot this. So far, my attempt looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_bitmovement <- function(bit_movement, highlight_bits) {
  ggplot(bit_movement, aes(
    y = positions,
    x = operation,
    group = factor(bit, levels = 1:32)
  )) +
    geom_line(colour = "gray") +
    geom_point(colour = "gray") +
    geom_line(data = highlight_bits, colour = "black") +
    geom_point(data = highlight_bits, colour = "black") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:31, labels = 1:32) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none"
    ) + ylab("Bit-position") + xlab("Operation")
}
```

where I highlight the first or last byte in plots:

```
bit_movement <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:31, rot_hash_positions))
plot_bitmovement(bit_movement, bit_movement %>% filter(bit < 8))
```

[image: Highlighted first byte that is added.]

```
last_byte <- tibble(bit = 0:7, operation = 4, positions = 0:7)
plot_bitmovement(bit_movement, last_byte)
```

[image: Highlighted last byte that is added.]

The last byte is less interesting in this case, but I need to visualise some other hash functions as well where it gets more interesting.

Now my problem is this: When I plot the bit-movement using `geom_line()`, I do not get line segments from one y-axis level to the next, but horizontal line segments for all but the first step from one level to the next. What I want are only segments that go from one level to the one below. I am not entirely sure how to do this.

I'm thinking that `geom_linesegment` is the way to go, in which case I need to modify my `bit_movement` data frame to something that has the start and end positions of the line segments I want, but I am not sure how to do that in an elegant way. And since I need to plot several similar figures, I would prefer not to have to hardwire too much of the data manipulations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately it's slightly difficult to understand what you are looking for. Any possibility to make a smaller example and provide a corresponding 'drawing' of your desired output? Cheers.

Comment: The drawing in my own attempt, below, shows what I am aiming for. I want to plot segments that show how the individual bits move in each combine+mix operation in the hash function. I do that in my own attempt below... now, I guess, I am just looking for an elegant way to do it. What I have now will work, except that I have to hardwire how many operations I make in both the function for computing the hash function -- where I will always need it -- and in the calls to the `get_steps` function. I guess I could get it using max over operation, though...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this idea. I am not sure how elegant it is, so I would still love comments on it.

```
library(purrr)
get_steps <- function(bm, step) {
  op1 <- bm %>%
    filter(operation == !!(step-1)) %>%
    mutate(x = operation, y = positions) %>%
    select(bit, x, y)
  op2 <- bm %>%
    filter(operation == !!step) %>%
    mutate(xend = operation, yend = positions) %>%
    select(bit, xend, yend)
  inner_join(op1, op2, by = "bit")
}

plot_bitmovement <- function(bit_movement, highlight_bits) {
  bm_segs <- map(2:4, ~ get_steps(bit_movement, .x)) %>% bind_rows()
  hl_segs <- map(2:4, ~ get_steps(highlight_bits, .x)) %>% bind_rows()
  ggplot(bm_segs, aes(
    x = x, 
    y = y, 
    xend = xend,
    yend = yend)
  ) + 
    geom_segment(colour = "grey") +
    geom_point(colour = "grey") + 
    geom_point(aes(x = xend, y = yend), colour = "grey") +
    geom_segment(data = hl_segs, colour = "black") + 
    geom_point(data = hl_segs, colour = "black") +
    geom_point(aes(x = xend, y = yend), data = hl_segs, colour = "black") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:31, labels = 1:32) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none"
    ) + ylab("Bit-position") + xlab("Operation")
}

bit_movement <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:31, rot_hash_positions))
plot_bitmovement(bit_movement, bit_movement %>% filter(bit < 8))
```

[image: Flow of first byte with geom_segment.]

**Update:** No, this isn't quite right either. Now I see more movements than I should since I combine all positions at one level with all below. That is an error in `rot_hash_positions`, though, so I'll give that a go myself.